# Alerts without page reload Rails AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a model `Snippit` and I want users to be able to delete a snippit, from a list, and then show an alert saying it was deleted, all using ajax. I have figured out how to do the actual deleting, but not the alert.

Here's the code:

**snippits_controller.rb**

```
  def destroy
    @snippit = Snippit.find(params[:id])
    @snippit.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to snippits_url}
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.js {render :alert => "Sippit destroyed. "}
    end
  end
```

**destroy.js.erb**

```
$('#snippit_<%= @snippit.id %>').remove();
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @snippits.each do |snippit| %>
      <span class="panel panel-default" id="snippit_<%= snippit.id %>">
      <%= link_to edit_snippit_path(snippit), :class => "text" do %>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <h3 class="text"><%=snippit.title%></h3>
          <p class="trash"><%= link_to snippit, method: :delete, remote: true do %>
            <i class="fa fa-2x fa-trash-o"></i>
          <% end %></p>
          </div>
          <% end %>
          </span>
    <% end %>
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a JS alert response, then you'd want something like the following instead

```
format.js {render js: "alert('Sippit destroyed.');"}
```

The format.js render above means you're rendering a JS response. Your alert `render :alert => "Sippit destroyed. "` only works for HTML response because the `flash[:alert]` is rendered in the HTML page, but since you are rendering a JS response, then you'd either do the JS alert implementation above OR you partially update the HTML page to update the flash message by something like the following

destroy.js.erb

```
$('#snippit_<%= @snippit.id %>').remove();
$('#flash_container').html('<%= j render partial: "flash_container" %>');
```

**UPDATE (Added working controller code for method 2: using destroy.js.erb above)**

```
def destroy
  @snippit = Snippit.find(params[:id])
  @snippit.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to snippits_url}
    format.json { head :no_content }
    format.js { flash.now[:alert] = @snippit.destroyed? ? 'Sippit destroyed.' : @snippit.errors.full_messages }
  end
end
```

I added a failure-handler code above for `format.js`. It will set the flash alert message into either 'Sippit destroyed' if `@snippit` was successfully destroyed, OR into 'Some failure to destroy error' if `@snippit` was not destroyed.

Comment: I tried both ways, but neither of them worked out, when I tried them the whole thing stopped working. Although I dont quite understand what to do in the second method. My alert wrapper has the id `alert_wrapper` and the actual alerts id is `alert` , can you guide me from there?

Comment: I updated my answer to show what the controller should look like when using options 2: `destroy.js.erb`

Comment: You need to put your `<div id='alert_wrapper'>...</div>` into a separate partial file. So say your alert wrapper is inside `application.html.erb`, then you move them into a partial file (i.e. `/layouts/_alert_wrapper.html.erb`), then render that partial file in `application.html.erb`: `<%= render partial: 'alert_wrapper' %>`. Now that it has been moved to a partial, you can now then easily update that alert wrapper through AJAX with my answer above: `$('#alert_wrapper').html('<%= j render partial: "alert_wrapper" %>');`

Comment: I updated my first method answer which has missing `js: `. That should work now.